# MongoDB: $Push Does not Update Document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update a MongoDB document using the $push command. It instead creates an additional array object instead of appending it to an existing one. When I used $set, it overwrites the existing data and replaces it with the data that should have been appended.

Here is my MongoDB document:

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"62e89560059e092e53796b97"},
"submissionDate":"$date":"2022-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"},
"userID":"B0k3qww4pdRGWqPaB2xTLF25A5n1",
"TrainWise":{
  "competitionTrack":[{
    "competitionName":"UCLA Match",
    "positiveMood":["Energized","Breathing","Hopeful"],
    "negativeMood":["Breathless","Nervous"],
    "submissionDate":{"$date":"2022-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"},
    "competitionDate":"08/01/2022",
    "competitionOpponent":"USC",
    "opponentRanking":"14",
    "competitionType":"Amateur",
    "eventRound":"3"}]}
}
```

Here is what I have tried to use to update the document

```
competition_track_data = {
  'rateWorthiness': {
    'questionPrompt': 'How strong was my feeling of worthiness and belief that I could win?',
    'questionResponse': '6'}, 
  'ratePhysicalPrep': {
    'questionPrompt': 'How well did I physically prepare for this competition?', 
    'questionResponse': '8'}, 
  'rateMentalPrep': {
    'questionPrompt': 'How well did I mentally prepare for this competition?', 
    'questionResponse': '6'}
}
```

This is my code for updating the MongoDB

```
trainwise_management_collection.update_one({
  "TrainWise.competitionTrack": { 
    "$elemMatch" : { "competitionName" : TrainWise.competitionTrack.competitionName, }},
  "userID" : user_id, 
},
{       
  "$push": {
    "TrainWise.competitionTrack.$": [ competition_track_data ],
   }
})
```

When I run this code, I get this error: "The field 'TrainWise.competitionTrack.0' must be an array but is of type object in the document." However, if I removed the $ sign, it does not update the matching document.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"TrainWise.competitionTrack.$"` - the `$` (dollar) at the end, what is it for? If you want to add an element (an object in this case) to an array field, just push into the field. The definition says: _"The $push operator appends a specified value to an array. And has a syntax: { $push: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$push`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) is for when you want to append a value to an array. What you're aiming to do is [`$set`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) fields on a document.

As you've figured out, you need to use the [`$` positional operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to tell MongoDB which document in the array you want to update.

The following code example is similar to the MongoDB documentation for [updating documents in an array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) with the positional operator:

```py
trainwise_management_collection.update_one({
  "TrainWise.competitionTrack": { 
    "$elemMatch" : { "competitionName" : TrainWise.competitionTrack.competitionName, }},
  "userID" : user_id, 
},
{       
  "$set": {
    "TrainWise.competitionTrack.$.rateWorthiness": {
      'questionPrompt': 'How strong was my feeling of worthiness and belief that I could win?',
      'questionResponse': '6'
    },
    "TrainWise.competitionTrack.$.ratePhysicalPrep": {
      'questionPrompt': 'How well did I physically prepare for this competition?', 
      'questionResponse': '8'
    },
    "TrainWise.competitionTrack.$.rateMentalPrep": {
      'questionPrompt': 'How well did I mentally prepare for this competition?', 
      'questionResponse': '6'
    }
  }
})
```